# Prevent wrapping destructured variables with Prettier in ES2018

Tags: prettier

What setting or magic word needs to be configured to prevent destructured ES2018 objects from wrapping?

For example, this...

```
import utils from '../../../utils';

const {
  email,
  strings,
  errors
} = utils;
const {
  init: error,
  BAD_REQUEST
} = errors;

const validate = (req, res, next) => {
  const {
    email: value
  } = req.body;

  return next();
};

export default {
  validate
}
```

... SHOULD BE ...

```
import utils from '../../../utils';

const { email, strings, errors } = utils;
const { init: error, BAD_REQUEST } = errors;

const validate = (req, res, next) => {
  const { email: value } = req.body;

  return next();
};

export default {
  validate
}
```

Note: I've tried `printWidth` and it has no impact.

Comment: How is this a jslint or jshint question? I believe this is strictly a jsprettier issue, right? Unfortunately, Prettier only has an option in JS to [ignore a single line at a time](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#javascript) in imports. It's opinionated. ;^) Though check your [max length setting](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width), if you're in a situation where you can change it.